# loop carousel jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, carousel, infinite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [my carousel does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552242/my-carousel-does-not-work)

am a bit puzzled!
i got this carousel am creating and i desire that it loops.
everything else works out fine, but, when the last image has slid up
i want the first one to do the same after it, then the second...infinitely.
i have tried many things like appending the first image to the last.
i have also tried showing back the images after the last(this one tries but gives an undesirable effect).

i need to be shown what tweaks i need to make. thanks big time!

```
var images = $("#slideShow div");
var index = 0;
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    $(images[i]).addClass("image-" + i);
}

setInterval(function() {
    $(".image-" + (index)).slideUp(1000);
    if (index < images.length - 1) {
        index += 1;
    }   
    else {
        index = 0;
    }    
}, 500);


  #slideShow {
height:20em;
width:80%;
float:right;

}

#slideShow div{
line-height:20em;
float:right;
}   

   #slideShow img{
vertical-align:middle;
border:solid 5px #A5A5A5;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
}

        <div id="slideShow">
                    <?php

                            $dir = "carousel";
                        $dh = opendir($dir);
                        while($slide = readdir($dh)){
                                $items[] = $slide;
                            }

                            for($i=0; $i<sizeof($items); $i++){
                                                            if($items[$i] !=   "." && $items[$i] != ".."){
                                                   $imagePath = $dir."/".$items[$i];
                                                   $image = "<div>"."<img src = \"".$imagePath."\""." />"."</div>";
                                                    echo $image;

                                        }

                                }
                            closedir($dh);

                        ?>

            </div>
```

Comment: Ah, without a pause? And btw, your slide animation is slower that the setInterval ticks. Makes no sense to me. A demo fiddle would be greatly appreciated

Comment: yep! no pause! yah i did that intentionally for development purposes; for i have a pool of images which a php script is reading from a folder. any help?

Comment: I have an idea, lemme just setup a demo ok? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of toggling your images that will make the code unreadable and full of z-index changes, **just `animate` the `scrollTop` of the container element**

- Animate the scrollTop and inside a callback, redo the loop function and:
- reset the scrollTop to 0 and
- remove the first element, appending it `after` the the last one

```js
var $slideShow = $('#slideshow');

function loop() {
  $slideShow.stop().animate({
    scrollTop: 200
  }, 800, 'linear', function() {
    $(this).scrollTop(0).find('div:last').after($('div:first', this));
    loop(); // Recursion
  });
}

loop(); // Start
```

```css
#slideshow {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slideshow img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/cf5&text=1" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/f0f&text=2" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/444&text=3" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/f70&text=4" alt=""></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: you have a demo. If you want to see what's happening just remove `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: @Wagaba... well? Any news? you're still trying?

Comment: wait a moment...should i do away with all my code, or? if not, where should i put this code, or what should it come after?

Comment: You can clearly see that in my demo there's not a "comma" of your code. Where's the issue bro?

Comment: hahahaha! lol! alright let me do that.

Comment: it is static, this time!

Comment: @Wagaba see in the demo, go to JSBin -> Download and take the time to explore! And lemme know if anything positive happened on your side! :) Don't forget to add the `document ready` function like in the code above

Comment: surprisingly the demo works just fine!

Comment: the only problem was that my div had an upper S in "slideShow" and i had just pasted your code that had a lowe s. now the problem is one: it does not scroll smoothly!

Comment: Change 'linear' to 'swing' if you like. And show a demo, cause here works fine

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make a second copy of your images, stick them on the end of the existing ones. That way when you pass the "last" image, the "first" image is visible.

The trick is then to reset the position of the whole lot once the copied "first" image gets to the end of the viewable area.

Comment: am trying to get your point, but it looks like i tried it already with the append(). this instead distorts my pictures, nothing beta. can you demonstrate, with reference to my simple lines of code?

Comment: alright! as per your request.this generates the html:  <div id="slideShow">
      <?php
                                
                                $dir = "carousel";
                            $dh = opendir($dir);
                            while($slide = readdir($dh)){
                                    $items[] = $slide;
                                }
        
                                for($i=0; $i<sizeof($items); $i++){
         if($items[$i] != "." && $items[$i] != ".."){
           $imagePath = $dir."/".$items[$i];
           //to be continued...

Comment: //continued here                                                    $image = "<div>"."<img src = \"".$imagePath."\""." />"."</div>";
           echo $image;
           
           }
           
                                    }
                                closedir($dh);
                                    
                            ?>
                     
                </div>

Comment: the css:#slideShow {
 height:20em;
 width:80%;
 float:right;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

#slideShow div{
 line-height:20em;
 float:right;
 } 
 
#slideShow img{
 vertical-align:middle;
 border:solid 5px #A5A5A5;
 border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 }

Comment: You should really edit the question and put the code samples there.